# Blockchains with modifiable consensus algorithm

Tags: blockchain, consensus

I'm looking for a blockchain which has a modifiable consensus algorithm. Does anyone know if there are some available or should I start from scratch creating one? Thanks in advance for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly this is what i was trying to create. I am trying to create a blockchain where the consensus should be pluggable depending on the trust assumptions of the business adopting the blockchain.This is the scratch of the project work i have done so far
https://bitbucket.org/mohor32/ownchain/src/master/
You can share your ideas with me or contribute if you feel so
Email : pythonesia12@gmail.com